# Getting error as "Application has been upgraded" while executing selenium script

Tags: selenium, firefox

Getting error as "Application has been upgraded" while executing selenium script

```
1503335038389   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1503335038402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1503335038434   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
1503335038452   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/PluginProvider.jsm
1503335038456   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: XPIProvider
1503335038458   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1503335038463   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous8300782133030252087webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1503335038467   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous8300782133030252087webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1503335038468   addons.xpi  INFO    Removing all system add-on upgrades.
1503335038472   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
1503335038478   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping aushelper@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1503335038484   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping e10srollout@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1503335038485   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1503335038783   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping screenshots@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
1503335038785   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping webcompat@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1503335038794   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1503335038794   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1503335038795   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1503335038799   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1503335038801   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
```

Code which i am executing

```
package newpackage; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 
public class Myclass { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\gecko‌​driver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
   String baseUrl = "facebook.com";;
   String tagName = ""; driver.get(baseUrl); 
   tagName = driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getTagName(); 
   System.out.println(tagName); 
   driver.close(); 
   System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Code which i am executing package newpackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Myclass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://www.facebook.com";
        String tagName = "";
  driver.get(baseUrl);
   tagName = driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getTagName();
    System.out.println(tagName);
    driver.close(); System.exit(0);}
}

Comment: what version of Firefox and Geckodriver? Make sure you are using the latest one